# Catching same exception thrown by different methods?

Tags: c#, exception

Have a look at the following code, where two methods throw same type of exception but have different context altogether.

```
class Test
{
 public void methodThrowingExceptionX()
 {
   //some code
   throw new X();
 }

 public void anotherMethodThrowingExceptionX()
 {
   //some code
   throw new X();  
 }
}
class TestClient
{
  private Test testObj = new Test();
  public Response TestMethodCaller() 
  {
    try
    {
       testObj.methodThrowingExceptionX();
       testObj.anotherMethodThrowingExceptionX();
    }

    catch(X xExceptionObj)
    {
      //this will catch X exception regardless from which method it is comming
      //How can i distinguish from where the exception is coming(which method is throwing)
      //so that i can return the Response object according to the context of the method which has thrown this exception?
    }
  }
}
```

Problem which I am having with above `catch` is that it catches exception of type `X` from both the methods. But my high level logic requires to have different `Response` objects (say, to have different language code, different message, different application specific code for exception cause) when `X` exception comes from different method or you can say that `Responose` should change according to the context.

What is the best way to achieve this?

**Edit**

Following code tells you why i want to do this

```
interface ICommand
{
    void execute();
}

//say we have some command implementation
class CommandA : ICommand 
{
  public void execute()
  {

    //some code 
    throw new X();
  }

}

class CommandB : ICommand 
{
  public void execute()
  {

    //some code 
    throw new X();
  }

}
class MacroCommand : ICommand
{
    List<ICommand> commands;

    public MacroCommand(List<ICommand> commands)
    {
        this.commands = commands;

    }
    public void execute()
    {
       foreach(ICommand command in commands)
       {

           //execute method of various commands can throw exceptions may of     same type say X.
           command.execute();
       }
    }
}

class Client
{

   List<ICommand> commands = new List<ICommand>();

   commands.Add(new CommandB());
   commands.Add(new CommandA());

   MacroCommand macroCommand = new MacroCommand(commands);

   try
   {

        macroCommand.execute();
   }

   catch(X xExceptionObj)
   {
     //How can i get the information which execute() actually thrown the exception??

   }

}
```

Comment: Surround each method call with a `try...catch`, then you know from where it's coming ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter actually i am implementing command pattern and have Macro Command where i have list of command objects in that case i do a foreach on the list to call same method on every object in list so i cannot do try catch differently on each method call.

Comment: Then the problem is between that foreach() and your "different responses" requirement. Don't blame the poor exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit,

In the macro execute you have the opportunity to enrich or encapsulate the exception:

```
public void execute()
{
   foreach(ICommand command in commands)       
   {
       try
       {
         command.execute();
       }
       catch(X ex)
       {
          // add one or more command related pieces of info to the exception
          ex.Data.Add("Command", command.Name);
          throw;
       }
   }
}
```

And then when you handle the exception higher up, you can have your ICommand back from `ex.Data["Command"]`

The alternative is a `class XWrapper : Exception` where you can add your own properties, and then replace the `throw;` with `throw new XWrapper(..., ex);` And of course you then have to `catch(Xwrapper xObj) ...` outside the loop.

Comment: At compile time It's saying cannot apply [] indexing operator to an expression of type Exception

Comment: And now it's giving run time exception saying  "Argument passed in is not serializable." when you do ex.Data.Add("Command", command)?? :(

Comment: OK, then go for the "any other piece of info" plan. What do you want to know from the Command when handling the exception?

Comment: basically i want to know from where the exception is coming so that i can create a context related Response object

Comment: That's not really answering my question. The 'where' is always the same spot inside the foreach. How do you get from an ICommand to the desired response?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132289/discussion-between-rouftantical-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: Hey i have found a better way with e.Source property. i can assign it with the name of the method.but i fear if it has some other use??

Comment: Yes, I would leave Source as is. Why not put that name into .Data ?

Comment: Source by default is having the project name in it which seems of no use to me so that's why i used it. But yes i can also put that into data no problem.

Answer (score 5):

The normal way is to surround both method calls with their own `try...catch`. On that way you always know what caused the exception and you can handle it separately.

If you want to avoid that for whatever reason you *could* use the [`Exception.TargetSite`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
try
{
    testObj.methodThrowingExceptionX();
    testObj.anotherMethodThrowingExceptionX();
}
catch (X xExceptionObj)
{
    MethodBase site = xExceptionObj.TargetSite;

    switch (site.Name)
    {
        case nameof(testObj.methodThrowingExceptionX):
            return blah....
        case nameof(testObj.anotherMethodThrowingExceptionX):
            return blub....
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unexpected method caused exception: " + site.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am editing the answer for more clarity on what i want plz have a look

Comment: @Rouftantical: it's still not clear why you can't use my approach to determine the method where the exception was raised. Apart from that, your exception `X` should contain the necessary details that you need to know as properties.

Comment: Instead of Reflection its simple to use ex.Source property to set it to method name and then compare it with method name.

Comment: @Rouftantical: the `Source` property gives you the name of the application where the exception occured

Answer (score 1):

The only clean way to achieve this is to have 2 `try..catch` blocks, one around each call.

An ugly/unmaintainable/unruly solution would be to use status variables and you check for in the catch block.

Comment: But i want to avoid that :(

Comment: Exception Filters and a Property in the Exception should also work if he is on VS 2015

Comment: Why you want to avoid that? If it's crucial to know where the exception was raised you have to try-catch both method calls separately

Comment: @TimSchmelter plz see comment in your answer

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for this, one is to use xExceptionObj.StackTrace which contains complete call hierarchy, so from that info you can search for required details. This is preferred in case if more than one parent is calling same method and you like to handle it part of base class.

[image]

And then the easy one which I prefer for you simple case is to use TargetSite Object

```
xExceptionObj.TargetSite.Name
```

output will be `"methodThrowingExceptionX"`
[image]